# Upload images to server in array form?

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, multipartform-data, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I need to send images data to server in array form.I need a sample code which should be accepted by server.In server our backend developers accepting like below format `{"images": {
  "name": ["Desert.jpg", "Hydrangeas.jpg", "Koala.jpg", "Tulips.jpg"],
  "type": ["image\/jpeg", "image\/jpeg", "image\/jpeg", "image\/jpeg"],
  "tmp_name": ["\/tmp\/phpubHwme", "\/tmp\/phpUjyQBx", "\/tmp\/phpajU78R", "\/tmp\/phplOpTne"],
  "error": [0, 0, 0, 0],
  "size": [845941, 595284, 780831, 620888]
 }}`

How should I change my code. I am sending like below

```
NSString *boundary = [self generateBoundaryString];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",API_URL,path]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *httpBody=[NSMutableData data];


for (NSString *key in [paramDict allKeys]) {


    [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\";",key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [httpBody appendData:[[paramDict valueForKey:key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [httpBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

}


NSInteger name=1;
for (NSData *data in images) {

    [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"images\"; filename=\"image%ld.jpg\"\r\n",(long)name] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: %@\r\n\r\n",[self mimeTypeForData:data]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [httpBody appendData:data];
    [httpBody appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    name=name+1;
}
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];

[httpBody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
```

If I use above method It is appearing like below format in server side

```
{
images =     {
    error = 0;
    name = "image2.jpg";
    size = 87611;
    "tmp_name" = "/tmp/phpO0LRJ2";
    type = "image/jpeg";
};}
```

In which format shall I send images ?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *imgTypeArr = @[@"image\/jpeg", @"image\/jpeg", @"image\/jpeg", @"image\/jpeg"];
NSArray *nameArr = @[@"image\/jpeg", @"image\/jpeg", @"image\/jpeg", @"image\/jpeg"];
NSArray *sizeArr = @[[NSNumber numberWithInt:845941], [NSNumber numberWithInt:595284],[NSNumber numberWithInt:780831],[NSNumber numberWithInt:620888]];
NSArray *error = @[@"0",@"0",@"0",@"0"];
NSDictionary *dict1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"name",nameArr,@"type",imgTypeArr,@"error",error,@"size",sizeArr, nil];
NSArray *dict2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"images",dict1,nil];
NSLog(@"%@",dict2);
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Create NSDictionary object like this.

```
NSDictionary *bodyDictionary = @{ @"images" : @{ @"name" : @[@"Desert.jpg", @"Hydrangeas.jpg"], @"type" : @[@"image/jpeg", @"image/jpeg"], @"tmp_name" : @[@"tmp/phpubHwme", @"tmp/phpUjyQBx"], @"error" : @[@(0), @(0)], @"size" : @[@(845941), @(595284)] } }
```

> 2. Convert Dictionary to Data

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:bodyDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
[httpBody appendData:data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

**Convert data to string check for created `json` format**

```
NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Json: %@", json);
```